# How to type response that returns object with unknown number of keys and key names?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Lets say i send http request using axios that returns something like this:

```
{
    "Some random name": {
        "401": [
            {
                "float": 0.0067058,
                "amount_added": 452.6,
                "modified": 1609051773409
            }
        ],
        "72": [
            {
                "float": 0.9,
                "amount_added": 100,
                "modified": 1609051773209
            }
        ]
    },
    "Some other random name": {
        "14": [
            {
                "float": 0.03325695,
                "amount_added": 629.1,
                "modified": 1609131583160
            },
            {
                "float": 0.03325694,
                "amount_added": 753.5,
                "modified": 1607779304000
            }
        ],
    }
}
```

Axios will return AxiosResponse type for which i need to define data

```
AxiosResponse<Data>
```

Now I am not sure how to type Data since object keys are random as well as keys inside

Comment: Will the structure always be an object of unknown string keys, where every value of those keys will be an object with unknown string keys, where every value of those inner keys will be an array of objects with `float`, `amount_added`, and `modified`?

Comment: `type Data = {
  [key: string]: {
    [key: string]: {
       "float": number;
       "amount_added": number;
       "modified": number;
    }
  }[]
}` ?

Comment: @Aplet123 yes that is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many approach to do this :

Using the "Record" type :

```
type SubData = Record<string, {
  float: number;
  amount_added: number;
  modified: number;
}>

type Data = Record<string, SubData[]>
```

Using interface or "type Data ="

```
interface Data {
  [key: string]: {
    [key: string]: {
      float: number;
      amount_added: number;
      modified: number;
    }[];
  };
}
```

Comment: I like the second approach but i think u need to type second object as array

Comment: My mistake, it's updated. Btw array type could also be written `Array<T>` instead of `T[]`